# Trigger option not working with parameter pipeline where pipeline running successfully in debug mode

Tags: azure, azure-data-factory

I have created parameterized pipeline in Azure data factory.
This pipeline runs fine if i run by clicking on debug.
But it is failing by executing through trigger option. it is not recognizing source database. Throwing below error.

> Error
>
> Operation on target Get Table And Procedure List failed: Failure
>   happened on 'Source' side.
>   ErrorCode=SqlOperationFailed,'Type=Microsoft.DataTransfer.Common.Shared.HybridDeliveryException,Message=A
>   database operation failed with the following error: 'Invalid object
>   name
>   'stg.controlTableLoop'.',Source=,''Type=System.Data.SqlClient.SqlException,Message=Invalid
>   object name 'stg.controlTableLoop'.,Source=.Net SqlClient Data
>   Provider,SqlErrorNumber=208,Class=16,ErrorCode=-2146232060,State=1,Errors=[{Class=16,Number=208,State=1,Message=Invalid
>   object name 'stg.controlTableLoop'.,},],'

Trigger option not working with parameter pipeline where pipeline running successfully in debug mode

Comment: It's difficult to troubleshooting your error based on the information you posted.`Invalid object name` means the table name is not recognized correctly,per my knowledge.How you configure the sql table name in dataset? Please post it!

Comment: The issue is resolve. it is somekind of refresh issue as my Data Factory link service was point to wrong secret name where as my local DevOps branch was point to correct secret name.

As trigger always point to data factory ARM template JSON, Trigger option was failing with data source issue.

Re-publish from my GIT branch resolve this issue.

Comment: Well done, i tried to summarize your solution as an answer.You could accept it to end this case for others' reference on the forum.Thx.

Answer (score 0):

Just for summary:

It is some kind of refresh issue as Data Factory link service was point to wrong secret name where as local DevOps branch was point to correct secret name. As trigger always point to data factory ARM template JSON, Trigger option was failing with data source issue.

Re-publish from Git branch resolve this issue.